# C# Logging Method Execution Performance using Interceptors for normal classes without Interface

Tags: performance, logging, interceptor

This query is regarding performance logging.I am using Log4net for logging.
I want to log the time execution for particular method.
I have came across Interceptors for logging using Unity Container but its all about Interface and virtual method.
In my C# .Net project we have not use interfaces but abstract classes and other normal classes.
Is there a way I can use interceptors for logging execution of methods of any normal class?

I am not looking for paid option.

Thanks,
Suraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a open source library to get method time execution.
Its methodtimer Fody nuget Package.
More information here : https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer
When you add this nuget, FodyWeavers.xml file gets added to project.
Inside this file, you need to add MethodTimer tag inside the weaver tag 
Hope this information found helpful to the viewers.

Thanks,
Suraj